# How to use tuples to slice a list?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have generated a list of tuples using the combination function in itertools package. How can I pass that to a list of integers to slice it? Here is my sample code, but gives me an error because of the tuple:

```
from itertools import combinations
myNumbers = [12,4,5,6,7,9,3,2]
listOfIndexes = list(range(8))
comb = combinations(listOfIndexes, 3)
for i in list(comb):
    print(myNumbers[int(i)])
```

my expected output is to print all combinations of 3 numbers in myNumbers, such as:

```
12,4,5
4,5,6
5,6,7
...
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @JacobIRR thanks. I just edited the question and added the expectation. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want to print all *consecutive* combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works:

```
from itertools import combinations
myNumbers = [12,4,5,6,7,9,3,2]
listOfIndexes = list(range(8))
comb = combinations(listOfIndexes, 3)
for i in list(comb):
  a,b,c = myNumbers[i[0]], myNumbers[i[1]], myNumbers[i[2]]
  print(a,b,c)
```

... but as far as I can tell, the above code just does this in a less efficient way:

`print([i for i in combinations(myNumbers, 3)])`

Comment: You can use `a, b, c = operator.itemgetter(*i)(myNumbers)` as well. The OP doesn't actually want a slice, but an arbitrary set of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample output, it looks like you aim to print all *consecutive* three elements of the list. This is something different, and we do *not* need combinations for that.

We can slice the list with:

```
myNumbers = [12,4,5,6,7,9,3,2]
for i in range(len(myNumbers)-2):
    print(myNumbers[i:i+3])
```

or we can print the items with a comma as separator with:

```
myNumbers = [12,4,5,6,7,9,3,2]
for i in range(len(myNumbers)-2):
    print(*myNumbers[i:i+3], sep=',')
```

This then prints:

```
>>> for i in range(len(myNumbers)-2):
...     print(*myNumbers[i:i+3], sep=',')
... 
12,4,5
4,5,6
5,6,7
6,7,9
7,9,3
9,3,2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations
myNumbers = [12,4,5,6,7,9,3,2]
listOfIndexes = list(range(8))
comb = combinations(listOfIndexes, 3)
for i in list(comb):    
    print(*[myNumbers[ij] for ij in i],sep=',')
```